# Alternative way to show a UIPageControl (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to add an arrow or like an image to correlate to how many view I have in my UIScrollView in swift. Something in line of this [image] [image]

(UPDATE) - My question is how do you insert an image into your scrollview that will tell it to go forward or backwards depending on how many images you have.

Now I know there is the UIPageControl but I'm looking into an alternative way to show that there is a picture and to the right or right and left. This is the code I have so far. I'll try the best I can to explain what I'm doing.

1. My picSource.count is data from a website that is carrying pictures
2. I'm multiplying my number of views by the screenwidth
3. This is an if else statement that shows if a picture is there post bgImage if not post no photoprovided image.

Let me know if you need more information or if I should revise. Thanks!

```
// Gallery
        if (picSource.count > 1){

            var picNum:CGFloat = CGFloat(picSource.count)

            // UI News Image Scroller
            var scroll = UIScrollView(frame:CGRectMake(-5, 650, screenWidth, 260))
            scroll.pagingEnabled = true
            scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(picNum*screenWidth, 220)

            // Number of views
            var numberOfViews = picSource.count
            var imageName = ""

            // Loop to add views to scroll view
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++){

                var myIntValue:Int = Int(screenWidth)

                var xOrigin = i * myIntValue

                // Creates UIImageView instance using myImage
                var scrollImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xOrigin, y: 5), size: CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 250)))

                // Tests which image name needs to be used
                imageName = picSource[i]


                // Creates image object using specified image name "...jpg"
                var url = NSURL(string: "http://www/images/cl/" + adID[adCurrentTag] + "/gallery/" + imageName)
                var maybeError: NSError?

                if var imageData :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &maybeError) {

                    var bgImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    scrollImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                    scrollImageView.image = bgImage
                    // Adds Image to scroll view
                    scroll.addSubview(scrollImageView)

                }else if let error = maybeError {

                    var photoNotProvided = UIImage(named:"noPhoto800x800.png")
                    var photoNotProvidedView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 650.0, screenWidth, 300.0))
                    scrollImageView.image = photoNotProvided
                    scroll.addSubview(scrollImageView)


                }
            }


            border.addSubview(scroll)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is your question ? You look for a way to display arrows, or to place your imageViews in your scrollview, or want to know how to use a pageViewController ?

Comment: Sorry for being vague my question is how do you insert an image along with your UIScrollView. Like if the image is there then put an arrow aka(UIImage) pointing to the next image and if the next image has another image in front of it then put an arrow to the right and left signifying that you have an image in back of it and in front.

Comment: I would approach it through an Object Oriented design.  Create a UIView subclass that holds an UIImageView and forward/back arrows and exposes properties as to whether these should be shown/hidden. I would also set up a delegate protocol back from the UIView subclass so that it could notify the containing UIViewController that the forward/back arrow had been pressed.

Comment: I'm very new to Swift so how would I do this?